# Alternative currencies eWallets

Tags: alternatives, services, e-wallet

Are there any online wallet services that offer services for alternative cryptocoins, such as Namecoins, Litecoins, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [btc-e](https://btc-e.com/) exchange for example.